# Angular build configurations variables

Tags: angular, production-environment

I added a new environment to my angular app and it works fine. 
Now I want to control the build so that I would be able to see the source code in the browser developer tools but it would be built and act like production. 
I'm assuming I can control the way the code is building with the config variables like:

```
{
   "optimization": true,
   "outputHashig": "all"
   ...
}
```

but i can't find any explanation about the way these vars affect so can someone give me a hand?
thnx

Comment: I would say rather `production:false`.

Comment: check this one https://blog.angularindepth.com/becoming-an-angular-environmentalist-45a48f7c20d8

Comment: production: false won’t do the job and in the linked article there is an explanation about how to set new environment which I already did. I just want to run the command ‘ng build -c myConfiguration’ and to see that in the dist folder the code isn’t minified so i would be able to see the source code